# Import Data into Spreadsheet - Refresh Automatically

Tags: google-docs

I would like to import data into a Google Document each day automatically without having to do it manually. I have about 50 numbers I need to import, each from a different page. One looks like this: http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/sweatingthebigstuff.com

I want the 244,604 imported into my document and to refresh automatically. Once I get the code for doing it once, I'll be able to repeat it for the other information too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Spreadsheets has [developer APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html) for .NET, Java, PHP and Python. So just [screen-scrape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) the Alexa page and update the document via the API, in the language of your choice.

Comment: I have no idea how to do any of that...interested in helping me out?